# Is it true that first surgeons were barbers?

Tags: medicine

Talking with a friend, he told me that the first surgeons were the barbers. In part it made sense as they are used to cut and cure people as they shave them. Even the striped bar red white and blue comes because of the bandages hanging outside tinted white or tinted in blood.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: I don't know how much people know about this. But as far as India is concerned, the first surgeons were scholars who were well-educated people and were knowing a good deal about human anatomy besides being authors of treatises related to surgery. They are still regarded as Rishi or sages  - http://ispub.com/IJPS/4/2/8232

Comment: Yes, The novel **The Physician**, deals with this matter giving a fair idea of how medicine was practiced in the 11th centry Europe/Middle East. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Physician

Comment: I am not sure if we can call them surgeons, but barbers and other "non-professionals" were routinely conducted procedures that now we consider surgical in eg Medieval Europe. Note that it often means fixing up injuries, treating wounds, etc, so situations where any intervention is generally a better choice than no intervention.

Comment: This question isn't answered by the "History" link on the [Wikipedia page for Barbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber#History), is it?

Comment: @T.E.D. The article does not go into the aspect that in the countryside Barbers were the only medical help really available.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: That link appears to be to a *predatory journal* - one that will publish for a fee virtually anything submitted.

Comment: The wikipedia page  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_surgeon seems to have basic info on this.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, Horse leeches and apothecaries often acted in a medical capacity when they were the only ones having any sort of medical knowledge.

Comment: There are a lot of sources on this history of surgery; as others have said, the first surgeons were in stone age times, so little is known about who did it or why: maybe it was by priests/shamans, maybe by specialists, maybe just by ordinary people. We do have some evidence about ancient Egyptian surgery, which appears to have been done (at least for the wealthy) by professional physicians. But things like pulling teeth or battlefield medicine could be done by anybody. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_medicine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider carefully how you asked your question. I think the useful statement would be

*It is true that, at some time in the past, barbers provided some surgical procedures while physicians did not.*

But that is not actually the answer to the question you asked. There is evidence of surgical procedures from [thousands of years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_surgery#Origins) ago, long before the barbers you associate with the striped poles. So barbers were **not the first** surgeons.

"The past" is not a single point in time. It different from century to century, from region to region. An answer that would be correct for 16th century Europe could be wrong for 3rd century China.

Many people who ask and talk about history will either overestimate or underestimate ancient civilizations. Take the famous [Antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism), a kind of mechanical calculator for astronomical events. When it was found, the reaction by many experts was "wow, I didn't think that the ancient Greek were *that* advanced." What some sloppy journalists made out of it was "advanced civilization in ancient Greece." But even with Antikythera mechanism, the ancient Greek were less advanced than 20th century science. Probably even less advanced than 13th or 14th century science, overall.

Comment: I want to upvote but I'm not sure about that last sentence.

Comment: @bonzo-lz, horse collars, three-field system, crucible steel ...